# Targeting UI elements dynamically with Appcelerator Alloy?

Tags: dynamic, uiview, appcelerator

Is there a way to target a specific alloy UI element **by passing a variable**? I would like to pass a variable like so:

**controller.js**

```
var flag = "se";
changeBackground(flag); //should change the background color of ImagView of the se flag


function changeBackground(elementToChange){
    elementToChange.backgroundColor = "red"; //does not work
   $. + elementToChange +  backgroundColor = "red"; //does not work
}
```

**view.xml**

```
<View id="flagRow" layout="horizontal" backgroundColor="blue" height="Ti.UI.SIZE">
    <ImageView id="se" height="20dp" left="5dp" image="/images/flags/se.png" onClick="downloadPastLanguageLevels"/>
    <ImageView id="de" height="20dp" left="10dp" image="/images/flags/de.png" onClick="downloadPastLanguageLevels"/>
    <ImageView id="en" height="20dp" left="10dp" image="/images/flags/en.png" onClick="downloadPastLanguageLevels"/>
            </View>
```

Right now I am looping through the $.flagRow. container but I would rather know how to set the flag directly.

```
var i, view;
    for (i in $.flagRow.children) {
            view = $.flagRow.children[i];
            if (view.id.indexOf(flag) > -1) { 
                view.backgroundColor = "red";
            } else {
                view.backgroundColor = "transparent";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Really need to avoid putting styling in XML especially dp - it's not necessary as is the default.

Comment: yes, i know. im putting things into .tss always at the end. during development i find it easier first inline because i often need to change things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reference elements in a view from the controller by using $.id so if you had an element called "myButton" you would reference it as $.myButton. If you were passing the name as a variable to a function expecting a parameter called "element" then you'd address it as $[element] where element is a string representing the id so "myButton" in this case.

In your case changing the code to reference $[elementToChange] should do it.

Comment: Just for more info to @user24957, it's a core JavaScript concept that how we access keys of an object dynamically. $ is an object containing every id of Alloy elements + lot other stuffs in it. Read more here about using **[JavaScript Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)**